# Validation rule: Regex characters not allowed asp.net mvc model validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

For Asp.Net mvc model validation I'm trying to create a regex for the following requirement:

- string length between 1-5 (including 1 and 5 limit)
- non word characters are not allowed
- underscore not allowed

I can write a regex witch matches the non word characters but not the inverse of my question.

**Regex**

Non word characters and underscore match:

> ([\W_])

String length between 1 and 5:

> {1-5}

**Asp.net mvc Code:**

```
namespace x
{
    public class Model
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"")]
        public string AString {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^\W_]{1,5}$
```

Se the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ3zY7/1)

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\W_]{1,5}` - not a non-word character and not a `_` 1 to 5 occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

The `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that *matches any character that is **not** in the character class*.

Also, when you want to limit string length with a regex, you need to use some boundaries. In this case, you can rely on the usual start/end-of-string [**anchors**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).